# Can a primitive value be considered an object in java?

Tags: java, object

When I started out using Java, it was implied to me that we have two different types:

```
Objects (strings, from classes, println, etc)
primitive values (int, double, char)
```

I just got back an exam from a Professor where this difference would mean the difference between two choices as answers. When I asked my professor to clarify, he told me that primitive values can be objects.

Who is right here and can anyone give me any proof?
Proof would be something official sounding and I would choose that as the answer as well as awarding you some proverbial internets.

Comment: The correct terminology is primitive type and reference type.

Comment: Then look into boxing conversion.

Comment: Primitive values can be "boxed" and "unboxed" into/from reference types, which is sometimes done automagically.

Comment: `float` and `boolean` are also primitive types, their "boxed" versions being `Float` and `Boolean`.

Comment: What is the exact question?

Comment: Can a primitive value be considered an object? is the exact question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a primitive value be considered an object?

The answer is No.

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) states

> There are **two kinds of types** in the Java programming language: primitive types (§4.2) and reference types (§4.3). There are, correspondingly, **two kinds of data values** that can be stored in variables, passed as arguments, returned by methods, and operated on: primitive values (§4.2) and reference values (§4.3).

Those are  [Primitive Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) which are

> predefined by the Java programming language and named by its reserved keyword

and [Reference Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3) which can be one of

> class types (§8), interface types (§9), type variables (§4.4), and array types (§10).

Note also that there is a special type which is `the null type` and its corresponding value `the null reference`

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null (§3.10.7, §15.8.1), which has no name.
>
> ...
>
> The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null type.

For the primitive types the JLS has defined a mechanism called [Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) for converting them into the corresponding reference types.

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type.

So since there is the need for a **conversion** to go from a primitive type to a corresponding reference type one cannot say that primitives can be considered as objects and vice versa. But  one can say they are convertible.

Comment: You get all my internets for the day.

Comment: @munchschair, Thanks, hope that's enough prof for your proof :pun alarm:

Comment: MFW being a good student and seeing details that a professor has missed works against me.

Comment: @munchschair heh, hope your prof is fine with being corrected, so good luck!

Comment: Update; he didn't think so. le sigh; he said he meant objects just as in things in the array. But he gave me points back on the test; he just didn't recall on what.

Comment: All you said was "reference types" can be converted to "value types".
Nothing in what you quoted states that ONLY "reference types" == "objects".

Answer (score 11):

Primitives are not objects. Which is to say, an `int` is not an `Integer`.

However, with any vaguely-recent Java compiler, a primitive can be [auto-boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) as an associated object type (`int` autoboxes as `Integer`) and [auto-unboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) (`Integer` unboxes as `int`), and the instances of the object types related to primitives (`Integer`, `Long`, etc.) are immutable (which is important for behaving like their primitive counterparts), and so the distinction becomes blurry. That may have been what the professor was alluding to.

That is, a method (for instance) accepting an `int` can be given an `Integer` and the compiler just handles unboxing it; similarly, a method accepting an `Object` (maps come to mind) can accept a primitive, and the compiler boxes it into the corresponding object type.

Comment: Yes, and what school is this?

Comment: Technically, that's a matter of the compiler, not the JVM.

Comment: I can't say that, don't want to get in trouble. But if I am right, my gpa would gain a boost.

Comment: @munchschair Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit mapping between primitives and objects, so an `int` can be used where an `Integer` is expected. It is a feature called autoboxing.

For example:

```
Integer foo = 4; // 4 is really an int
```

Also, primitives have things in common with objects. They have a `Class`, such as `int.class`.

It should also be noted that all arrays are objects.

However, the notion of Object vs primitive is one of the worst thing there is in Java. A lot of modern languages simply don't make too much difference between them, or even don't have any primitives. (In java as well, you can do everything without ever using explicitly a primitive).

Comment: On java 10 maybe, it is said that they would remove primitives.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : the formulation is indeed clumsy. I will reformulate.

Comment: Now, it's a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

**ONE LINE, QUOTING THE SPEC!!!!**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf

> An object is a class instance or an array.

```
Conclusion:
value/primitive types are __NOT__ objects.
reference/class types are         objects.
```

Also, all objects extend class object.
And the instanceof operator does not work with value types:

```
int a; //:<-- int is [value/primitive] type version 
       //:    of Integer [reference/class] type.
if( a instanceof Object ){ ... } //:<-- SYNTAX ERROR
```